# Slice Intersection in D

Tags: d, intersection, overlap, pretty-print, slice

Have anybody implemented intersections for array slices that overlap in memory? Algorithm returns `[]` upon no overlap.

I want this when pretty-printing (using overlap indentation) arrays slices that overlap in memory.

Comment: Does anybody have suggestions for other reference types in D for which this kind of pretty-printing could be useful? This idea is somewhat similar to the semi-automatic visualization features present in the Data Display Debugger (DDD).

Answer (score 3):

if you are sure they are arrays then just take the difference of the `ptr` fields:

```
size_t startoffset = b.ptr-a.ptr
```